# QUERY Syntax with multiple cell references

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

First time posting. I'm having difficulty with the syntax for a query I'm making in Google Sheets, the function is as follows:

```
=MAX(QUERY({'Fall Scoresheet'!$B$9:$V$2009;'Winter Scoresheet'!$B$9:$V$2009;'Spring Scoresheet'!$B$9:$V$2009},"Select Col10 where Col4 contains '"&$C42&"' and Col2 >= '"&Instructions!$O$21&"' and Col2 <= '"&Instructions!$O$22&"'",0))
```

Its returns a #N/A error stating that the "Query completed with an empty output".

I have tested and hard coding the references works; example below:

```
=MAX(QUERY({'Fall Scoresheet'!$B$9:$V$2009;'Winter Scoresheet'!$B$9:$V$2009;'Spring Scoresheet'!$B$9:$V$2009},"Select Col10 where Col4 contains '"&$C42&"' and Col2 >= 3 and Col2 <= 5",0))
```

I expect it to return the maximum value from multiple sheets based on the conditions in the function. Am I missing something simple? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try skipping the apostrophe `'` for the parts thats handling the `numbers` and see what happens. So this `'"&Instructions!$O$21&"'` becomes `"&Instructions!$O$21&"`. Same goes for `'"&Instructions!$O$22&"'`as well. the string part `'"&$C42&"'` remains as is...*

Comment: That did it! You're the man! What's the reasoning behind dropping the apostrophe?

Comment: Your `Col2`→ *number data-type* is not the same as `'"&Instructions!$O$21&"'`→ *plain text data-type* (due to the usage of single quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a number, you change the following sentence: and Col2 >= '"&Instructions!$O$21&"' and Col2 <= '"&Instructions!$O$22&"' to and Col2 >= "&Instructions!$O$21&" and Col2 <= "&Instructions!$O$22&"' (Note the removal of commas)